# Combobox custom control with a lid

Tags: vb.net, combobox, custom-controls

I have created a custom combobox with a label to cover the combobox (as it's very ugly) when it's not in use. The label, witch is the lid should show the display member. The covering and uncovering forks fine however the text on the label displayed is the previous value and not the current one. Passing over the label with the mouse, triggers the labels mouse enter event and than the display value is correct. 
Here is the code for the custom control.

```
Public Class ComboBoxWithALid
    Inherits ComboBox
    Private WithEvents Lid As New Label With {.BackColor = Color.LightCyan, .ForeColor = Color.Black,
       .TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter}
    Protected Overrides Sub OnDataSourceChanged(ByVal e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnDataSourceChanged(e)
        Lid.Location = Location
        Lid.Size = Size
        Parent.Controls.Add(Lid)
        Lid.BringToFront()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Lid_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Lid.MouseEnter
        Lid.SendToBack()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)se
        Lid.Text = SelectedText
        Lid.BringToFront()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnDropDownClosed(e As EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnDropDownClosed(e)
        Lid.BringToFront()
        Lid.Text = SelectedText
    End Sub

End Class
```

To test the control, drag the control from the tool box to  your form and bind the control to any table you have

I tried to use text in place of selected text - same results

I found the solution. Change the move statement to:

```
Lid.Text = Items(SelectedIndex)(DisplayMember)
```

and is works.

Answer (score 0):

`SelectedText` is for the highlighted portion of the text that is currently selected, not the selected item.  You probably want something like this:

```
If SelectedIndex = -1 Then
  Lid.Text = String.Empty
Else
  Lid.Text = Items(SelectedIndex).ToString()
End If
```

Yes, you have an annoying control.

Comment: That should probably be `Text` rather than `SelectedValue`, given that the question imprecisely says that it should show the display member rather than the value member.